# Convert string into list of different types in python

Tags: python, string

I have strings with numbers and characters in the format below:

```
sign = "[[1,2,3],4,'message',2,[4,5,6],7]"
```

I would like to separate the string into its different elements so that I can access them, for example:

```
sign[0] = [1,2,3]
sign[1] = 4
sign[2] = 'message'
sign[3] = 2
sign[4] = [4,5,6]
sign[4][0] = 4
sign[5] = 7
```

Is there any simple way to do this in python3?

Comment: it depends on how you got that string. Just eyballing it you can probably achieve what you want with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: @josh `eval()` is overkill (and possibly unsafe). Use `ast.literal_eval()`. See the link I posted.

Comment: Please **do not** use `eval` without first understanding the [implications and potential risks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/6340496).

Comment: the strings will always be the same format, will only change the values of numbers, I think that for this case it's ok to use eval

Comment: The best solution to this problem is usually "don't convert the list to a string in the first place".  If you *have* to convert a list to a string and you want to be able to turn it back into a list later, use `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` instead of `str()` and `eval()`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but in this case I had to upload data in an ethereum smart contract so it is easier to store in string format.

Comment: @Cesar11031: `ast.literal_eval` does what you need, and can't run arbitrary code like `eval` (e.g. `eval('__import__("subprocess").run(["echo", "pwned"])'))`), closing off most security concerns. Do *not* use `eval` here, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: You should listen to all the folks warning you about `eval` its sometimes fine, and only really good as a temporary fix until someone posted a more flesh out answer

Comment: @Cesar11031: Also, your response to Samwise doesn't make sense. `json.dumps` produces a string too, so even if you need string formatting, `json.dumps` works. `json.loads` is also somewhat faster to parse input than `ast.literal_eval` (though it doesn't handle quite as many types, it handles all the stuff you've got here), so it would work just fine, and would let you load your data in non-Python programs too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the answer about using json before
It makes a lot of sense, thanks for the clarification.